# PHP: use className in child class

Tags: php, oop

```
---- file 1 ----
use Models\Post;
class A 
{
    public function fct() {
        Post::all();
    }
}

---- file 2 ----
class B extends A {

}
```

How can i use Post in **class B** without write again **use Models\Post**.

Comment: It's a class in a different file, so you have to add the use statment again.

Answer (score 0):

Try This way

```
---- file 1 ----
use Models\Post as Post;
class A 
{
    public $post;
    // instantiate in __construct and store it to a public or protected variable

    public function __construct() {
       $this->post = new Post;
    }
    public function fct() {
        $this->post->all();
    }
}

---- file 2 ----
class B extends A {

}
```